# Открытие docx в richtextbox WPF

Tags: wpf, docx, richtextbox

Возможно ли открыть в контроле richtextbox WPF, вордовские файлы формата docx?
При этом не используя конвертирование файла на входе из docx в rtf

Comment: Что значит открыть контролом? 
Чем не устраивает такой алгоритм:
1) Открыть через OpenXML
2) Считать ввесь текст
3) Загнать в RichTextBox
4) Поработать с ним
5) ????
6) PROFIT
?

Comment: имел в виду открыть в контроле, мне нужно использовать только Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word сборку

Answer (score 1):

Вот код, который решает вашу проблему (не забудьте подключить директиву System.Microsoft.Interops.Word):

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            // Получаем путь до файла
            string originalfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFile.FileName);
            // Проверяем существует ли файл и соответствует ли расширение файла
            if (openFile.CheckFileExists && Path.GetExtension(originalfilename).ToLower() == "docx")
            {
                Application wordObject_first = new Application();
                object File = originalfilename;
                object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                Application wordobject_second = new Application();
                wordObject_first.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
                _Document docs = wordobject_second.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
                docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
                rtfMain.Document.Paste();
                docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
                wordObject_first.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);


                MessageBox.Show("file loaded");
            }
        }
```

[Ссылка на источник c кодом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32527242/13940541)

Я конечно знаю, что вы хотите решить через Interops, но может быть вам пригодится ссылка на статью с решением этой проблемы через библиотеку DOCX: [ссылка](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-file-in-WPF)